# GML line of sight not working

Tags: gml

Im am creating a game where the character will be able to run about a prison only able to see walls and characters within its line of sight. The following screenshot is the desired effect.

**Desired effect**
[image]

However I have a problem where some walls are covered up due to the top corner not being visible as seen here.

**Bottom right corner wall is covered**

[image]

I am using the following code

```
checkPlayersx = x
checkPlayersy = y

if(!collision_line(checkPlayersx,checkPlayersy,obj_player.x,obj_player.y,obj_wall,1,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

When looking at the bottom right block, the field of view is obstructed by the top and left tiles. You may have to find an other way to trigger this block.

You might encounter this issue with some other angular blocks too. What you could do is create a new object, that would have as parent the standard wall bloc, but it would take the ID of the adjacent blocks and light up if one of the adjacent blocks it lit up.

To detect the adjacent blocks during creation, it will be essential to create this block after it's neighbors. You can use the instance_nearest() function to detect them.

But the technique I would use is slightly different. I would create a cross-shaped sprite that would, when put in place of the block, cover the centers of the adjacent blocks, and use precise collision checking. At the creation of the wall, I would replace the wall sprite by the cross, and detect collisions with the adjacent walls. All adjacent walls IDs would be stored and checked every step for lighting in order to trigger the lighting of the wall. Then I would go back to the normal wall sprite, and voilà !

Hoping this helps.

Comment: Thanks that seems like it will work I am currently overwhelmed with work and as this is a passion project ill have to wait until I have some spare time to try it out. I really appreciate the help and ill let you know how it works out

Comment: Sorry my life has been really busy and i had almost completely dropped the project as i just didnt have the time. But i picked it back up today and just wanted to say thanks for the advice ive now got it all working and the line of sight code is working perfectly